# invalid use of group function while updating a column inside a table between two ranges of date

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

i have a table a_daily having 
columns like

```
1.date
2.FromDate
3.Target
4.Cumulative_Target
```

I will be adding the rows daily
so every day with reference to fromdate and date the Cumulative_Target column will be updated as shown in the table

This is what i need to do:

```
    date                Fromdate      Target          Cumulative_Target
    2012-04-16    2012-04-16    500              500                  '(cycle1-started)
    2012-04-17    2012-04-16    500              1000    
    2012-04-18    2012-04-16    800              1800 
    '
    '
    '
    2012-05-15   2012-04-16     200             xxxxxx                 '(cycle1-completed)
    2012-05-16   2012-05-16     150             150                     '(cycle2-started)
    2012-05-17   2012-05-16     100             250
    2012-05-18   2012-05-16     700             950
    '
    '
    '
    '
    2012-06-15  2012-06-15      200             xxxxx                    '(Cycle2-completed)
```

so the fromdate in the table will be varying per cycle

The query i used for updation is :

```
UPDATE a_daily 
SET a_daily.Cumulative_Generation = sum(a_daily.Target) 
    between a_daily.Date and a_daily.From_Date
```

I dont know how to do makeup the computed column Please help me!!

Comment: why ar eyou using a_daily_copy in update?

Comment: sorry now i have edited the querry

Comment: is there any alternative solutions ????

Comment: You will need to use a second table or first select the date, store it somewhere and than update your table.

Comment: what is that cumulative_generation column

Comment: Whay do you nee to store this data in the table? You always can calculate it useing SELECT query.

Comment: for front end reporting purpose i need the cumulative_target value as a calculated one !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE a_daily
  SET Cumulative_Target = @count:= target + @count
ORDER BY date
```

...specify your order clause if needed

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TableName a
       INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  DATE(a.date) date, 
                    date(a.Fromdate) fromdate,
                    a.target,
                     @accum:=@accum + a.runningTotal AS TOTAL
            FROM 
                (  
                  SELECT  DATE(date) date, 
                          date(Fromdate)Fromdate , 
                          target,
                          SUM(`Target`) AS runningTotal
                  FROM TableName
                  GROUP BY DATE(date), date(Fromdate),target
                  ORDER BY Fromdate
                ) a , (SELECT @accum := 0) s

        ) b ON DATE(a.Date) = b.date AND
               DATE(a.FROMDATE) = b.fromdate AND
              a.target = b.target
SET a.Cumulative_Target = b.total
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8931/1)